# Declaring two matrices in one line of code? Matlab 2014

Tags: matlab, matrix

,A simple question but one I have yet to get a concrete answer.  If I have two matrices, say A and B and I want to make them both the same size, say a 1x2 matrix of zeros. Is there a way to declare them both in one line of code?  I ask because in my situation I will have over 10 matrices of the same size but I want an easier way to declare them.

So at first I might think it would look like the following (which is not valid):

A,B = zeros(1,2)

Comment: See [`deal()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `deal()`-function does exactly what you are looking for. You can distribute either one input to several output-variables or also distribute several input values to several output values. You need the first case:

```
[A, B] = deal(zeros(1,2));
```